# Show loading bar on firebase CRUD request in Angular

Tags: angular, firebase

I have read that there is `ngx-progressbar` to automatically show progressbar when there is any http request. I wonder if there is any library or a way in Angular to show a progress bar when creating, reading, updating, or deleting data from firebase.

I have already did show the loading indicator, but its feels not quite good. I just give a `true` condition to the indicator tag when crud proccess started, and give `false` value if the proccess finished or failed. And sometimes, the indicator is gone when the data is not fully showed on page.

Any hint?

Comment: All xhr requests are async, so you can write a state about it and implement your own progress bar. There are lots of tutorials out there to achieve what you need, one of them is [here](https://medium.com/beautiful-angular/show-loader-on-every-request-in-angular-2-9a0fca86afef)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to implement the loading bar is to use INTERCEPTOR.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { LoaderInterceptorService } from './_services/loader-interceptor.service';
...
providers: [
  {
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: LoaderInterceptorService,
    multi: true
  }
]
```

**LoaderInterceptorService**

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, pipe } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { LoaderService } from '../_services/loader.service';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoaderInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private loaderService: LoaderService) { }
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.showLoader();
    return next.handle(req).pipe(tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => { 
      if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        this.onEnd();
      }
    },
      (err: any) => {
        this.onEnd();
    }));
  }
  private onEnd(): void {
    this.hideLoader();
  }
  private showLoader(): void {
    this.loaderService.show();
  }
  private hideLoader(): void {
    this.loaderService.hide();
  }
}
```

[Documentaion](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor)
[Read more](https://medium.com/@zeljkoradic/loader-bar-on-every-http-request-in-angular-6-60d8572a21a9)

Comment: Is this work for firebase mate? because in angularfirestore2, we don't use http. I dont know the proccess behind the scene, but what i know for sure. The crud proccess of firebase is not using http method (sorry i am new to angularfirestore2)